# set_error_handler gets called without an error

Tags: php

I was just playing around with `set_error_handler` for the first time,

I thought doing this, would actually only get called when an error happens,

```
set_error_handler(function(){
   die('ERROR');
})
```

But, not may page going black and shows that error only, when I don't have any error in my page. My question is, why does this happen?

Comment: Suppose you actually *had* an error on your page. How would you know what it was, when you don't *log* the actual error message anywhere?

Comment: You have missed the point of my question. I actually have error enabled, from strict to deprecated. So, I should be able to see if there is an error in my page, but It seems either I can't see the errors for some reason, or `set_error_handler()` is being called when no error is actually being triggered.

Comment: You have missed the part of the manual that says PHP's regular error handlers won't even be invoked (therefore your error will not get logged anywhere) unless your handler function returns `false`.

Answer (score 4):

The error handler gets invoked for all error levels. It doesn't respect the [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/error_reporting) level by itself. For instance an E_NOTICE would not be displayed by the default handler, but is still passed to your custom function.

```
$x = Ooops;  // Notice: undefined constant
```

Either probe the current error level in your custom handler, or set the `$error_type` flags with [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/set_error_handler) to mask when your function is invoked.

Comment: I have all errors enabled, from strict to deprecated, I have checked the page and no error are there, even in my log file, so I would like to know why this function is running without detecting an errors.

Comment: Just add the two parameters `$errno` and `$errstr` to your custom handler. Instead of just `die("ERROR")`, print them out with `die("ERROR: $errstr")` etc. That'll tell you exactly why it was invoked.

Comment: See the linked manual page once more. The `$errstr` parameter to the handler comes second. The `8` amounts to an E_NOTICE, btw.